# How to pass class objects as parameters for the function inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use class object as an argument inside the function defined in class:

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x
class klass(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self._func=func
    def plus(self):
        v_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        funcs=[func(v) for v in v_val]
        s=0
        for i in funcs:
            s=s+i
        return s


test=klass(f)
print (test.plus())
```

What should I do to pass the "object" as the argument "func" inside the "plus()" function?
I tried "self._func=func" but it doesn't work.

Comment: try it with `funcs=[self._func(v) for v in v_val]`

Comment: it works, I got it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `self.func` instead of `self._func` in `Klass.__init__()`
Then call `self.func` instead of `func` in the `funcs` comprehension in `Klass`

```
class Klass(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def plus(self):
        v_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        funcs = [self.func(v) for v in v_val]
        s = 0
        for i in funcs:
            s = s + i
        return s

def f(x):
    return 2 * x


test = Klass(f)
print (test.plus())
```